# Getting started with the facebook c# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook

This is my second post and I am going slightly mad. I have read all the posts on this forum an spent the best part of every night this week hitting my head against a brick wall. I am an experienced coder but I cannot for the life of me get my "facebook connect" to work.

What I think I want to do is;

I have a c# asp.net solution which is a webforms solution which I develop on visual studio 2010. I want a simple page which gets my information from facebook and shows me my name. The simplest of simple.

How far have I got? I have a facebook app with my "Site Domain" set to englandkorfball.co.uk. I have the "Site URL" set to http://www.englandkorfball.co.uk/test.aspx?app=1

I have downloaded and referenced the 3.5 framework SDK dlls from codeplex.

I have put on test.aspx, the simplest of code which I do no know how to show you here

Q1. Can I show you my code in an easy format? I cannot work out the formatting on the site.

it is from all the web examples involving `FB.init`, the meta declaration and the `fb:login-button`. This part works fine. I log out of facebook, click on the button and I get asked to log in. I remove the app and it asks me fine. All this is fine.

It is the server side bit which I cannot for the life of me work out. I have used

```
Authorizer authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);
if (authorizer.IsAuthorized())
```

and

```
Authorizer authorizer = new Authorizer(fbApp);
if (authorizer.IsAuthorized())
```

and

```
if (fbApp.IsAuthenticated) {
```

but nothing will induce a positive authenticated result.

Have I got the wrong end of the stick. How do I check if I am logged in server side?

Thanks, I have run out of ideas and patience for something which could be so good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step buide on how you create a [Facebook Application with ASP.NET](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/wiki/Facebook%20application%20development%20in%20ASP.NET.ashx?NoRedirect=1), if you follow this throughly step by step, you will have a working app in no time. You have to be sure that the web.config part is exactly what it should be, here's an explanation of it:

- appId – Application ID
- appSecret - Application Secret
- baseDomain – Site Domain
- cookieSupport –“false”
- maxRetries – “2” (or the number of times you want the SDK to retry an action)
- retryDelay – “1” (or how long do you want it to wait before retrying

**Samples from [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/)**

- [ASP.NET MVC Sample](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation)
- [WebForms iFrame Sample](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebForms%20iFrame%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: ok, the answer for anyone who gets similarly stuck is that you need to pass in the Facebook Settings constructor with the app id and secret. The Javascript API on the Aspx page I surmise has put a cookie on my machine, which the server side code then picks up to create the auth code.Thanks

Comment: @Davros, don't forget to click the "Accept answer" button if this helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, this did not answer my question. The starter kit would not install because it could not find a bunch of .exclude files.

At the time I wrote this I clearly had no idea what the difference between a canvas app and integrating the SDK into my own website. I was at this point trying to write a webservice. This is my issue with all this. there is absolutely no guidance anywhere so I cannot even ask the right question. 

I have answered my own question by realising it makes no sense. the frustration reaches week 6

Comment: @Davros, I think you need to read the guidelines step by step again and see to it that you have all prerequisites.

Comment: thanks filip, I will, but i am pretty sure that I did what was expected. If this solves one of my many questions, I will credit you. Thanks for your time